# how to prevent groovy RESTClient from url encoding a path with %2F codes in it?

Tags: groovy, couchdb, cloudant

I have some groovy code to make a GET request against a server:

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def server = new RESTClient( 'https://myaccount.cloudant.com'  )

// the id contains a forward slash, i.e. xxxx/yyyy

response = server.get (path: 'aaaa/xxxx%2Fyyyy', 
         contentType: JSON, requestContentType: JSON)
```

However, the following is getting sent to the server:

```
"GET /aaaa/xxxx%252Fyyyy HTTP/1.1"
```

When it should be this:

```
"GET /aaaa/xxxx%2Fyyyy HTTP/1.1"
```

It seems like groovy is encoding the path - how can i prevent this?

Comment: could you just replace the '%2F' with a space char in the path value you're passing to the get method?

Comment: the '%2F' is a forward slash, and needs to be encoded for the server to realise that it's not a path component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import groovyx.net.http.URIBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

def server = new RESTClient( 'https://myaccount.cloudant.com' )

def uri = new URIBuilder(
    new URI( server.uri.toString() + '/aaaa/xxxx%2Fyyyy' )
    )

response = server.get (
            uri: uri, 
            requestContentType: JSON
            )
```